# window.closed Fails in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I'm having a strange problem with Javascript's `window.closed` property in Safari.
When I open a new window and navigate in that window, the closed property will always remain false after closing.

Is this default behavior in Safari? I have no problem in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

My code:

```
var winRef = window.open(someURL);
// ... Polling logic ...
// Navigate in the opened window and close it.
console.log(winRef.closed); // Will output false even though the window is closed.
```

It seems that the `winRef` variable looses its reference to the window during a page navigation.

**The following steps will produce the problem in safari**

1. Use the sample code located here: http://jsfiddle.net/CMK7h/9/ and open in Safari
2. Navigate in the opened window to a different page (do not use google search because this doesn't cause a page navigate)
3. Now close the opened window
4. The console should still be outputting 'Open'.

Answer (score 0):

The closed property should be false as long as that window is still open.

Here is an example of it working correctly. The alert will display true if it's closed, false if it's still open.

http://jsfiddle.net/QHXcG/2/

Comment: The problem i'm having is that when i open a new window and navigate in that window then chrome and safari looses its reference to that window which causes closed to remain false after closing.

Comment: If all you are doing is navigating in that window, then it is technically still open, and the value will remain false because it is open. I tried this in both FF and Chrome, getting the same results. If it is open, even after navigating, it is returning false because the window is still open.

Comment: The following code sample will always return false when navigating in the opened window and closing it (use Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/CMK7h/9/

Comment: Both of those fiddles work properly for me. If I navigate in the opened window, then close it, the next console log says "closed".

Comment: Which Safari version are you using (mine is 5.1.7 [7534.57.2])?